# shapeshifter-dispatcher giving a transport error

Tags: python, go, vpn, openvpn

I am attemptign to setup shapeshifter-dispatcher with openvpn via softehter.

i get the following error on shifter launch

```
2020/09/08 14:02:04 [NOTICE]: dispatcher-0.0.7-dev - launched
2020/09/08 14:02:04 [INFO]: initializing server transport listeners
2020/09/08 14:02:04 [INFO]: shapeshifter-dispatcher - initializing server transport listeners
2020/09/08 14:02:04 [ERROR]: Error resolving Extended OR address "missing port in address"
```

this is how i launch it on server

```
./shapeshifter-dispatcher -transparent -server -state state -orport 127.0.0.1:21194 -transports obfs4 -bindaddr obfs4-<server ip>:999 -logLevel DEBUG -enableLogging
```

and on client side like this , i execute a bat file for launch

```
shapeshifter-dispatcher64.exe -transparent -client -state state -target %serverip%:21194  -transports obfs4 -proxylistenaddr 127.0.0.1:999 -optionsFile obfs4.json -logLevel DEBUG -enableLogging
```

this is my error [image]

Comment: you're running on windows. Maybe the firewall blocks it?

Comment: no firewall, all opened. even opened these ports in iptables and windows firewall  on purpose to make sure im not missing smth